# How to call outside function inside animate complete function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code in one of my websites. I have a declared function named "`pressedTab(tab)`".

When i try to call it inside the following animate complete function, `$('#firstShow').animate({'margin-left':'-='+go+'px'}, 1000, 'linear',function() {...pressedTab(tab);}` it's not working.

I know its a scope thing but can someone help me fix the code? The strange part is that this code for years it worked. The last year it's not working properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tab1').click(function () {
        name('tab1');
    });
    $('.tab2').click(function () {
        name('tab2');
    });
    $('.tab3').click(function () {
        name('tab3');
    });

    function name(tab) {
        function pressedTab(tab) { //FUNCTION THAT I NEED HELP WITH
            if (tab == 'tab1') {

                $('#img-2 #folder-tab-3').removeClass('zindexUp').removeClass('zindexDown').addClass('zindexDown');
                $('#folder-tab-1').removeClass('zindexUp').removeClass('zindexDown').addClass('zindexUp');
                $('#folder-tab-2').removeClass('zindexUp').removeClass('zindexDown').addClass('zindexDown');
                $('.tab1 p').removeClass('current').addClass('current');
                $('.tab2 p').removeClass('current');
                $('.tab3 p').removeClass('current');

                $('#tug').hide('fast');
                $('#tugImages').hide('fast');
                $('#vessels').show();
                $('#vessels2').hide(0);
            } else if (tab == 'tab2') {

                $('#img-2 #folder-tab-3').removeClass('zindexUp').removeClass('zindexDown').addClass('zindexDown');
                $('#folder-tab-1').removeClass('zindexUp').removeClass('zindexDown').addClass('zindexDown');
                $('#folder-tab-2').removeClass('zindexUp').removeClass('zindexDown').addClass('zindexUp');
                $('.tab1 p').removeClass('current');
                $('.tab2 p').removeClass('current').addClass('current');
                $('.tab3 p').removeClass('current');

                $('#tug').hide('fast');
                $('#tugImages').hide('fast');
                $('#vessels').hide(0);
                $('#vessels2').show();

            } else {

                $('#img-2 #folder-tab-3').removeClass('zindexUp').removeClass('zindexDown').addClass('zindexUp');
                $('#folder-tab-1').removeClass('zindexUp').removeClass('zindexDown').addClass('zindexDown');
                $('#folder-tab-2').removeClass('zindexUp').removeClass('zindexDown').addClass('zindexDown');
                $('.tab1 p').removeClass('current');
                $('.tab2 p').removeClass('current');
                $('.tab3 p').removeClass('current').addClass('current');

                $('#tug').show();
                $('#tugImages').show();
                $('#vessels').hide(0);
                $('#vessels2').hide(0);
            }
        }

        if ($('#firstShow').attr('time') == "0") {
            var go = "250";
            $('#firstShow').animate({
                'margin-left': '-=' + go + 'px'
            }, 1000, 'linear', function () {

                $(this).attr('time', "1");
                $('.tab1').attr('time', "1");
                $('.tab2').attr('time', "1");
                $('.tab3').attr('time', "1");
                //Show the right folder
                $('#folder-tab-1').show("fast");
                $('#folder-tab-2').show("fast");
                $('#img-2 > #folder-tab-3').show("fast");
                //Hide the Upper of the folder
                $('#img-1').hide("fast");
                $('#firstShow #folder-tab-3').hide("fast");
                //alert(tab);
                pressedTab(tab); //FUNCTION WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO BE CALLED BUT IT'S NOT
            });

        } else {
            pressedTab(tab);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you add jsFiddle for us?

Comment: Better you move the `pressedTab` function to outside of the `name` function

Comment: I don't see any reason why you put `pressedTab` function inside `name` function..

Comment: I have tried before to keep outside the function from name but with no luck. i tried it again just in case but still no luck. That's not the problem @ChamikaSandamal

Answer (score 1):

Callback function in `animate(...)` will be call after `name(tab)` in context which do not have access to scope of `name(tab)` function, but it have access to global scope. Try to put `pressedTab(tab)` outside `$(document).ready(...)` it should work.

Comment: i did as you suggested but still not called

Comment: Try [example](http://jsfiddle.net/06qbrrxh/1/) on jsfiddle. As you can see its not a scope problem. Maybe structure of your site was change (elements now have another id and classes) or some other function named pressedTab overwrite your function..